# Fetch-retry npm testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch

retry npm package with global fetch.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-retry

Using it via:

```
const fetch = require('fetch-retry')(global.fetch)
```

For my unit tests, the suite fails saying `fetch must be a function`. However if I remove fetch-retry package my tests work. Fetch-retry is wrapping global fetch. Anyway to mock/test this?

My unit tests is something like this, as you see it doesn't have fetch-retry

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';

import Test from "./Test";



describe("Test", () => {
    let originalFetch;

    beforeEach(() => {
        originalFetch = global.fetch;
    global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve({
            value: "Testing something!"
        })
    }));
});

afterEach(() => {
    global.fetch = originalFetch;
});

it('Should have proper description after data fetch', async () => {

    // need to put mock logic here to make it work

    render(<Test />);
    const description = await screen.findByTestId('description');
    expect(description.textContent).toBe("Testing something!");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply this fix.

Create a file `getFetch.ts`:

```js
import getFetchWithRetry from 'fetch-retry';

export const getFetch = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    return {
      fetch: () =>
        Promise.resolve({
          ok: true,
          statusText: 'OK',
          json: () => Promise.resolve({}),
        }),
    };
  }

  return {
    fetch: getFetchWithRetry(global.fetch),
  };
};
```

And then use it like this:

```js
const { fetch } = getFetch();

fetch(…)
```